# Minor Magic Talent

Tags: pathfinder-1e, rogue

The Minor Magic talent allows a rogue to cast a 0-level spell from the wizard/sorcerer spell list either three times a day (for  the standard rogue) or at will (for the Unchained rogue).  Is that any spell at all, with no restrictions on spells known?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to be "from the sorcerer/wizard spell list", there is no other restriction. However you have to choose wich spell when you choose the talent, and can't change that choice without retraining.

Comment: It usually says so explicitly if you need to choose an option when you take a feat or talent.  There's no such stipulation here.  (And nice Freudian slip with that "witch spell :-) )

Comment: You can consider that as one of the inconsistencies in these rulebooks, it's not the first neither the last. If you didn't have to choose one, it would say "cast any spell of the sorcerer/wizard list". Here the sense is clear: you can cast only one spell.